# findstr not generating output

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a txt file:

```
#deployment.properties
#Thu Dec 22 13:48:41 PST 2016
deployment.modified.timestamp=1482443321245
deployment.roaming.profile=false
deployment.version=8
deployment.browser.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe
#Java Deployment jre's
#Thu Dec 22 13:48:41 PST 2016
deployment.javaws.jre.1.location=http\://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=
deployment.javaws.jre.0.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=
deployment.javaws.jre.1.enabled=false
deployment.javaws.jre.1.registered=true
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osarch=x86
deployment.javaws.jre.0.osname=Windows
deployment.javaws.jre.1.product=1.6.0_45
deployment.javaws.jre.0.platform=1.8
deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_111\\bin\\javaw.exe
deployment.javaws.jre.0.location=http\://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
deployment.javaws.jre.1.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe
deployment.javaws.jre.0.enabled=false
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osarch=x86
deployment.javaws.jre.1.osname=Windows
deployment.javaws.jre.1.platform=1.6
deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.8.0_111
```

In my batch file I run the command to output to a text file any line which contains the word product:

```
findstr /n "product" C:\myfile.txt > product.txt
```

The file is always empty, but the string exists in the original text file. Why is showing up blank?

Comment: Well if you are trying to write the file to the root of the C: drive it will error out.  By default you don't have permissions to write to the root of C:.  Is your input files Unicode?  If so use the FIND command.

Comment: @Squashman sorry it is not actually in C:\ root it is in a directory I have permission too. Find works, but it cause some strange output. It prints some hyphens, file path, and the line. I am just interested in the line. Can I do anything to just have the line printed? I looked at the find options doesn't seem like it? Is there a command to convert the input file to the proper encoding before I find?

Comment: Ahh I just tried to pipe it:  find /n "product" C:\myfile.txt > product.txt | findstr /n "product" and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: `type "C:\myfile"` can be used to do the conversion: `type "C:\myfile" | findstr /N "product" > "product.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this!

```dos
Find /N ".product"<C:\myfile.txt>product.txt
```

And obviously 'to just have the line printed'

```dos
Find ".product"<C:\myfile.txt>product.txt
```